# Parse a complex data type from the URL in Web.Routes.Boomerang

Tags: haskell, web-routes-boomerang

I am building a sitemap using `Web.Routes.Boomerang` package, and I want to use dates from `Data.Time.Calendar` in it:

```
data Sitemap = Index
         | Yearly Integer
         | Monthly Integer Int
         | Daily Day

sitemap = mconcat
    [ rIndex
    , rYearly . integer
    , rMonthly . integer </> int
    , rDaily . integer </> int </> int  -- does not typecheck
    ]
```

This does not typecheck, because the type for `rDaily` is

```
rDaily :: Boomerang e tok (Day :- r) (Sitemap :- r)
```

and not

```
rDaily :: Boomerang e tok (Integer :- (Int :- (Int :- r))) (Sitemap :- r)
```

I want to convert from `(Integer :- (Int :- (Int :- r)))` to `(Day :- r)`. Looks like `xpure` can help me:

```
dayr :: Boomerang TextsError [Text] r (Day :- r)
dayr = xpure mkDay parseDay . (integer </> int </> int)
    where mkDay (y :- m :- d :- x) = fromGregorian y m d :- x
          parseDay (day :- x) = let (y, m, d) = toGregorian day in Just $ y :- m :- d :- x

sitemap = mconcat 
    [ rIndex
    , rYearly . integer
    , rMonthly . integer </> int
    , rDaily . dayr
    ]
```

However, `fromGregorian` from above is not complete, and I would like to use `fromGregorianValid`:

```
fromGregorian :: Integer -> Int -> Int -> Day
fromGregorianValid :: Integer -> Int -> Int -> Maybe Day
toGregorian :: Day -> (Integer, Int, Int) -- for completeness
```

How do I flip `dayr` around to make things like `2014/95/13` invalid URLs?